# Google maps API v3.40 Data.StyleOptions interface --> Shape

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a circle around a marker in order to determine a boundary or area range. I need just a circle, there is no need for a polygon, with a point and radius it should be enough to draw it. What I want is exactly this:

[image: Dot shape example]

I'm loading the map data with the function `addGeoJson` in this way (I attached an example of the server response at the end of the question just in case):

```js
var promise = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/targets/");
promise.then(function(data){
    map.data.addGeoJson(data,{idPropertyName:"id"});
});
```

As a result, I get this map where there is a mark for every point:

[image: Current marker]

As I'm not manually iterating over each marker of my data, I would like to style them in a generic way. Looking for a way to change the marker style in google API reference I found that the [DatasStyleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.StyleOptions) allows me to define the shape of the marker through the *shape* property which is a [MarkerShape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerShape). So, I ended up trying this solution:

```js
 map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var geo = feature.getGeometry();
        //when it's a point
        if(geo.getType().toLowerCase()==='point'){  
         return {
             shape: {type: 'circle', coords: [geo.get().lat(), geo.get().lng(), parseFloat(feature.getProperty("radius"))]}
         };
        }
    });
```

> The *Shape* object looks like this:
>   `{"type":"circle","coords":[30,30, 5000]}`

The code above didn't make any change, the result still being the same, only markers were displayed on the map. I found a workaround for this but from my point of view, it is not the best way to deal with the problem and I don't understand why the solution described before is not working. Here is my current solution:

```js
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var geo = feature.getGeometry();
    //when it's a point
    if(geo.getType().toLowerCase()==='point'){
        //create a circle
        feature.circle=new google.maps.Circle({map:map,
                                            center: geo.get(),
                                            radius: parseFloat(feature.getProperty("radius")),
                                            fillColor: '#f00',
                                            fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                            strokeWeight: 0});
        return {
            visible:true,
        };
    }
});
```

> `GeoJSON` example:
>
> ```js
> {
>     "type": "FeatureCollection",
>     "features": [
>         {
>             "id": 1,
>             "type": "Feature",
>             "geometry": {
>                 "type": "Point",
>                 "coordinates": [
>                     -101.25,
>                     30.751277
>                 ]
>             },
>             "properties": {
>                 "user": 2,
>                 "title": "play station",
>                 "radius": "4500.00"
>             }
>         },
>         {
>             "id": 2,
>             "type": "Feature",
>             "geometry": {
>                 "type": "Point",
>                 "coordinates": [
>                     -101.25,
>                     50.751277
>                 ]
>             },
>             "properties": {
>                 "user": 2,
>                 "title": "Xbox 360",
>                 "radius": "6969.00"
>             }
>         },
>         {
>             "id": 3,
>             "type": "Feature",
>             "geometry": {
>                 "type": "Point",
>                 "coordinates": [
>                     -56.1,
>                     -34.9011
>                 ]
>             },
>             "properties": {
>                 "user": 2,
>                 "title": "Nintendo",
>                 "radius": "5000.00"
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly and what *doesn't work*? Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue including a full sample of the GeoJSON file and a clear problem description.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?  Looks to me like the longitude and latitude are reversed in your GeoJSON:  [30.751277,-101.25,45] (should be longitude, latitude; latitude can't be less that -90...)

Comment: There is no "type":"circle" in GeoJSON. Your "workaround" is probably the best way to achieve your desired result (the other option would be to calculate the equivalent circular Polygon and add that to the GeoJSON)

Comment: Or in the [`Data.StyleOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.StyleOptions) object that can be returned by the `setStyle` function.  The shape property is an image map for the Marker's Icon. (per the documentation: "Defines the image map used for hit detection.")

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for your answer. Well, those coordinates were just an example, the shape object works fine (I tried with hardcoded values). 
Oh, so, do you think my workaround is the best way? As I understand the `setStyle` function iterates over each point, seems quite inefficient. 
Is `shape` property an image? As I understood it's a [MarkerShape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerShape) whereas `icon` property could be a string, icon or symbol, but I think it is not for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MrUpsidown sorry, I changed a little the question in order to be more clear. I'm quite new on the platform and it is quite hard to make good questions and earn reputation. I hope I have explained myself well enough for removing that -1.

Comment: *`MarkerShape` This object defines the clickable region of a marker image.* Is this what you are trying to achieve? As I understand your question, you're just trying to display a Marker and a Circle so I don't see why you would need MarkerShape, unless you want the entire circle to be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to draw a circle around a marker in order to determine a boundary or area range.*

You can add your data to the map, then iterate over your data and for each `Point`, add a `Circle` to the map, if a `radius` property exists. That's how I'd do it.

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9011, -56.1);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var fc = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -101.25,
            30.751277
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "user": 2,
          "title": "play station",
          "radius": "4500.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -101.25,
            50.751277
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "user": 2,
          "title": "Xbox 360",
          "radius": "6969.00"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -56.1,
            -34.9011
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "user": 2,
          "title": "Nintendo",
          "radius": "5000.00"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  map.data.addGeoJson(fc);

  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {

    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {

      var radius = parseFloat(feature.getProperty('radius'));

      if (radius) {

        new google.maps.Circle({
          map: map,
          center: feature.getGeometry().get(),
          radius: radius,
          fillColor: '#f00',
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 0,
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

#### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5rwgjp16/)